# Why is this POST method not inserting data in my Postgres database in Node?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, postgresql, forms

EDIT: This is the error I recieved:

```
C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\lister\puupy\server.js:33
                if (err) throw err;
                         ^

error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "body"
    at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\lister\puupy\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:241:15)
    at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\lister\puupy\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:89:29)
    at Parser.parse (C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\lister\puupy\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\parser.js:41:38)
    at Socket.stream.on (C:\Users\przyb\Desktop\lister\puupy\node_modules\pg-protocol\dist\index.js:8:42)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! puupy@1.0.0 start: `node server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the puupy@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\przyb\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-07-19T01_30_59_800Z-debug.log
```

I am trying to insert data into a table in my postgres database using an HTML form and Node for server side. Here is the form:

```html
<form action="/" method="POST">
            <input id="Name" type="text" max="100" value="Doggy" name="name">
            <input id="query" type="submit" value="Submit">
```

Code to connect to db:

```js
const Pool = require("pg").Pool;

const pool = new Pool({
    user:"postgres",
    host:"localhost",
    database:"puppy",
    password:"Bolek_3003",
    port:5432
});
```

And this is how I am trying to actually insert the data:

```js
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false});

app.post('/', urlencodedParser, function(req,res,next){
    pool.query("INSERT INTO Users VALUES(null, req.body.name)",(err,res)=>{
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(err,res)
    });
    pool.end()
});
```

I don't know for how this data to actually be accepted into the database, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: I got the error ```error: missing FROM-clause entry for table "body"```, but I don't know what that means

Comment: try this see if it works var name= req.body.name ,const query = {text: 'INSERT INTO Users(column1, column2) VALUES($1, $2)', values: [null, `${name}`]} pool.query(query,(err,res)=>{...//}) the name part is between backticks

Comment: I tried that method, and I recieved this error: ```error: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1```. @Sven.hig

Comment: I have posted an answer check it out and see if it works for you

Comment: remove null from the array and use backticks " ` " " " around both ${req.body.name}` and ${req.body.number}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is a mistake in how the request is formatted

```
const query = {
text: 'INSERT INTO Users(column1, column2) VALUES($1, $2)',
  values: [null, `${req.body,name}`],
}
pool.query(query,(err,res)=>{...//})
```

or this

```
const query = 'INSERT INTO Users(column1, column2) VALUES($1, $2)',
values= [null, `${req.body,name}`]
}
pool.query(query,values,(err,res)=>{...//})
```

Comment: remove null from the array and use backticks " ` "  " `" around both `${req.body.name}` and `${req.body.number}`

Comment: This suggestion unfortunatley does not work for me. I tried it like this first: ```const query = {text: 'INSERT INTO Users(col1) VALUES ($1)', values: [null,`${req.body.name}`],} pool.query(query,(err,res)=>{...}); pool.end();```, but that caused the error: ```error: bind message supplies 2 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1.```. I also then tried ```const query = {text: 'INSERT INTO Users(col1,col2) VALUES ($1,)', values: [null,`${req.body.name}`,`${req.body.number]`,} pool.query(query,(err,res)=>{...}); pool.end();```.

Comment: this part` VALUES ($1,$2) ` specifies the number of values you want to pass and then you pass 2 values to the array`  [`${req.body.name}`,`${req.body.number]`] ` your array if fine just remove null from it

Comment: Ok I followed your instructions and correctly inserted the data, thank you very much for your time